# Is it safe to use Check and Require in production code? - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, testing, assert

I read from multiple sources is that we should avoid using `assert` in production, as an exception will not be thrown if the `-ea` flag is not enabled on the JVM.

However, as far as my understanding goes, the same does not apply `check` and `require`, i.e. they will always throw an exception regardless of JVM flags or any related settings.

I just wanted to double check that it is safe to use `check` and `require` by asking here before shipping to production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`require` and `check` are absolutely fine to use is production code, it throw a `IllegalArgumentException` in case of unexpected state, regardless of `-ea`.

Moreover, it can be considered as a good practice to do so, since it makes input checks consistent, more readable and allows smart casting to not-null type (via kotlin contract).